# Yaml instead of xml for testng test suite Intellij?

Tags: xml, maven, intellij-idea, testng, yaml

I'm working on converting our xml based testing suites to yaml based suites.
I think it will be easier to read.  I created a file that is testng.yaml that reflects my testng.xml.  Added below dependency to my pom.xml

```
name: TestNG
threadCount: 5

test:
  - name: testPMFRandom
    classes:
      - pmfsuites.TestPMF
```

Trying to figure out how to run this, I don't think intellij recognizes .yaml as a test suite.
My guts are telling me I need to have a yaml to xml converter somewhere.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: By "easier to read" do you mean easier for humans to read? In that case, perhaps you are using the wrong criteria. The main reason for using XML in preference to other formats is because there are so many tools for processing it.

Comment: Yes reading for humans... :)

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ doesn't support yaml for TestNG. You should vote for [the associated issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-94400).